# How to filter one pandas dataframe dates on the basis of other dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandasql

I have one dataframe, I need to filter the dates on the basis of start and end date of the other dataframe

example set is given below. What is the best way in pandas to achieve that?

Considering sample dataframes as below, I have included the expected result set

```
df1 

ID all_date   clicks
1  2019-08-21   5
1  2019-08-22   4
2  2019-07-18   5
2  2019-07-21   5
2  2019-07-23   6

df2

ID start_date  end_date
1  2019-08-21 2019-08-21
2  2019-07-18 2019-08-21
```

expected output:

```
df1

ID all_date   clicks
1  2019-08-21   5
2  2019-07-18   5
2  2019-07-21   5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&ei=z2VeXbmTBf7az7sPvuqC8AI&q=df+melt&oq=df+melt&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i7i30l2j0l2j0i30l3j0i5i30l2.3377.3650..3909...0.2..0.148.435.0j3......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.30PpV_2Ru88&ved=0ahUKEwj5tuynmpbkAhV-7XMBHT61AC4Q4dUDCAo&uact=5) and then `merge`:

First better to convert dates as datetimes just incase they are strings:

```
df1.all_date=pd.to_datetime(df1.all_date)
df2[['start_date','end_date']]=df2[['start_date','end_date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

---

```
df1.merge(df2.melt('ID',value_name='all_date').drop('variable',1),on=['ID','all_date'])
```

---

```
   ID   all_date  clicks
0   1 2019-08-21       5
1   1 2019-08-21       5
2   2 2019-07-18       5
```

Details, after `melt` you get:

```
df2.melt('ID',value_name='all_date').drop('variable',1)

   ID   all_date
0   1 2019-08-21
1   2 2019-07-18
2   1 2019-08-21
3   2 2019-08-21
```

Then join on `'ID','all_date'` on both the dataframes

Comment: thanks, could you please help me with the logic behind it

Comment: also I am not getting the desired result, getting an empty df @anky_91

Comment: @Dhiraj works for the input data.. is ID a column or an index?

Comment: yes it is column and it works for this sample bue i am actually i doing it for other larger data set where I am implementing this

Comment: **ValueError:* You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat m , this is the error i am getting now after conversion, also i have ID as alphanumeric

Comment: hmm.. change both the dataframe to datetime. check the first 2 lines of the code

Comment: got the issue, i had 2,3 more object type columns apart from this, so it worked on dropping off those, thanks much :)

Comment: @Dhiraj okay. thanks for letting me know Cheers..!!

Comment: @anky91 : one more doubt, what if we need to set a range from df2, like values of df1 should be between the start_date and end_date given in df2

Comment: @Dhiraj uhh, that would be a separate solution and approach I guess. I suggest you to please raise a fresh question:)